# How to see who consumes my webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

Is there any way to see who consumes my web service and how he uses it? Is there a logging system for that?

My consumer is not sure whether he is connected to my web service or not, and I cannot see that either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a logging library such as [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or the one in the [enterprise library](http://entlib.codeplex.com/)

If your service is a WCF service, adding an operation behavior allows you to perform some action every time an operation is invoked

```
internal class OperationLoggerBehavior : IOperationBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(new OperationLogger());
    }

    public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {
    }
}

internal class OperationLoggerAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        foreach (OperationDescription operationDescription in contractDescription.Operations)
        {
            if (!operationDescription.Behaviors.Contains(typeof(OperationLoggerBehavior)))
            {
                operationDescription.Behaviors.Add(new OperationLoggerBehavior());
            }
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }
}


internal class OperationLogger : IParameterInspector
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Called before an operation is invoked.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="operationName"></param>
    /// <param name="inputs"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        // Write to log     
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called after an operation has been invoked.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="operationName"></param>
    /// <param name="outputs"></param>
    /// <param name="returnValue"></param>
    /// <param name="correlationState"></param>
    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {
        // Write to log     
    }
}




// Service contract implementation    
[OperationLogger]
[ServiceBehaviorAttribute(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public partial class MyService : IMyService
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see exactly what messages your service is receiving.

It's good to add logging to to see exactly what your service is doing with the messages, something like [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) is very good.

Without both of these setup you won't be sure what is going on.